# Install manually grails

Tags: eclipse, grails, plugins

I want to know how to install manual a grails plugin (2.0.3 version) in STS.

I found grails plugin here http://grails.org/download

I tried to install it by cliking on Help -> Install New Software -> Clicking ‘Add’ then I had this error "Could not find jar:....grails-2.0.3.zip!"

Thanks

Comment: I cannot find any Eclipse plugin at http://grails.org/download, only Grails itself. Are sure that you've downloaded an Grails Plugins for Eclipse from here?

Comment: I want to only install Grails plugin. I've installed STS previously

Comment: you mean '*a grails plugin for eclipse*' or what? maybe you want to get *Grails*, not *Grails plugin*?
PS I though STS is already contains a plugin for grails development...

Comment: I'm using Spring source, I cannot install grails extention from the dashboard. That's why I'm looking for alternatif solution to install a specific grails plugin version.

Comment: Yes I thinkh I need 'a grails plugin for eclipse'

Comment: then you should download it from here - http://grails.org/products/ggts

Comment: I'll re start my environment set up. 
I see that there is not information about grails version. Can I change grails version after installing the 'package'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In STS go to `Window > preferences> groovy > grails` and select a grails directory for a particular version.

Also you can download the latest release and compiler from `Dashboard > Extensions`.

Comment: I selected my grails versions but ggts doesn't recognize my project as grails project. The convert processus and the compilation doesn't work.
The Console I have:
| Loading Grails 2.0.3
| Configuring classpath
And anythink else

Comment: The grails version and project version must be same And in your case your project is not a grails project .Its not recommended but you can try to create a new project and manually put src into new project if conversions to grails not working.

Answer (score 0):

In STS go to options like Window-->Preference-->Groovy..>Grails--> then click add button locate the Grails path which you located in your system

Comment: I did it, I selected grails 2.0.3 The problem now is when I tried to import my grails project the compilation stop at: 
| Loading Grails 2.0.3
| Configuring classpath

Comment: I don't know how but the project it recognize as grails project.