# STS - Failed to import grails project

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I encountered several issue in importing grails project

After importing my grails project with GGTS 3.4.0 I can't do anything:

The import action action freezes at 50%, so I stop it.

'Update grails dependencies' action doesn't stop so I deselect the 'Keep external Grails running' option.
Clean and compile action triggered an an exception after a while:

"Problem executing: clean
The command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe (23 déc. 2013 13:52:45)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time limit in the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch"

It's really frustrating I could not do anything for several hours.

This topic follows this one: [Install manually grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739748/install-manually-grails/20740774?noredirect=1#20740774)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the lower version sts 3.3.0. I know this doesn't resolve the issue which you are facing but for sake of other  workaround hope this helps.

http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.3.0/dist/e3.8/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.3.0.RELEASE-e3.8.2-win32-x86_64-installer.exe

Regards..